# How to format a windows service with vs template?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I'm creating a windows service in c# visual studio ultimate..
vs gives a template to use but I'm not sure where to put my code. there is program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

and service1.cs the sample code shows how im formatting it but im not sure that what im doing is right. ive searched quite a bit but cant find what way to structure my program

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    Thread thread1;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        thread1 = new Thread(function);
        thread1.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    public void function()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //keep doing something
        }
    }
}
```

Where do I call the loop function? Where I've placed it or from the main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine looks more like this:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase 
{ 
    Thread thread1; 
   Boolean running = false;

    public Service1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 

        thread1 = new Thread(function); 

    } 

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) 
    { 
        thread1.Start(); 
        running = false;
    } 

    protected override void OnStop() 
    { 
        running = false;
        thread1.Stop(); 
    } 

    public void function() 
    { 
        while (running) 
        { 
            //keep doing something 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is nothing wrong with putting `function()` into the `Service` class. It is more a question of design at that point. For example, is what `function()` does similar to the other operations in the class? I would guess not, since the others relate to interaction between the class and the Service Control Manager (SCM).

However, there are two issues with the code:

1. Start the thread in OnStart rather than in the constructor, since that is when the service starts.
2. Include some way for the function to stop, such as a bool flag.

Answer (score 0):

You should remember, that the constructor of `Service1` will be executed not only when service will be started through SCM - it will be executed even if you will click at service executable in Explorer.

That's why to put any service payload into ctor is a bad idea - it is better to put service initialization code into `OnStart` method, and finalization code (e.g. stopping worker threads, cleaning up resources) - into `OnStop` method.

Note, that `OnStart`/`OnStop` methods are very limited on  their execution time.
If you're planning to execute heavy initialization code, consider using of lazy initialization, where it is possible.

Also, consider using `ThreadPool`/TPL instead of manually creating threads.